# Cannot create new tensorflow keras model from model subset during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a [`tensorflow.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)
and for reasons that go beyond the scope of this question,
I'm using a custom [`tensorflow.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LambdaCallback)
to save the model at the end of the epoch.
As part of said callback,
I wanted to only save a subset of the model
(by cutting of the last couple of layers and a few inputs only needed for training).
To that end,
I get input layers by name from the model using `model.get_layer("some_name").input`
and `.output` respectively for some outputs.

Now when I try to create a new model using `tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer, other_input_layer], outputs=outputs)`,
I get an error message about an unconnected graph,
where the second layer doesn't find the first input layer:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(...), name='some_name', description="created by layer 'some_name'") at layer "...". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

This surprises me, because
a) I just trained this model no problem.
b) I can use this function that creates the submodel outside of the training context and it works.
c) if I clone model and apply the function to the clone, it also works.

I must not understand some element of the tensorflow workings under the hood.
Does anyone know,
why I would not be able to create a new model from the existing model during training?

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, simply cloning the model before making any changes. I assume that tensorflow manages some state underneath, when training, which prohibited what I wanted above, but cloning the model works.